# Does anyone know about the Static Shared Library?

Tags: linker, shared-libraries

Does anyone know about the Static Shared Library? Please describe the difference between it and the static library, and the difference between it and the shared library.

My own understanding is that static shared libraries can be shared by multiple processes, but the virtual address is fixed, such as 0x1000 in each process. While static libraries cannot be shared by multiple processes, shared libraries can be shared, but the virtual address is different in each process, such as 0x1000 in process 1 and 0x7000 in process 2.

This static shared library is said to have existed in early Linux systems.

I didn't find any information about it, just a few words in a technical book.

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone know about the Static Shared Library?

*No such thing* ever existed / was named that.

> This static shared library is said to have existed in early Linux systems.

Yes, *shared libraries* (not *static*) with "to be loaded at a fixed address" dynamic linking did exist on Linux before Linux switched to using ELF format.

> I didn't find any information about it, just a few words in a technical book.

The switch to ELF happened around 1995, so almost 30 years ago. The terms to search for are a.out-format shared libraries. You should also limit your search to "before 1996".